# php strtotime function is not returning correct date

Tags: php

My php code is showing all messed up dates.

```
$d='2016-08-17T09:47:36Z';
echo(date(" d M, Y G:i:a", strtotime($d)));
//shows  17 Aug, 2016 5:47:am
```

Why is it not showing 17 Aug, 2016 09:47:am

Comment: it's working:-https://eval.in/623748  and https://eval.in/623749

Comment: Open into separate file and check it because its working fine here.

Comment: @Anant, it is because eval.in uses UTC and iso dates also using UTC. https://eval.in/623755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to different timezones, you need to set `UTC` timezone for this,

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$d='2016-08-17T09:47:36Z';
echo(date(" d M, Y G:i:a", strtotime($d)));
```

Refer [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more info and [online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2707826223a3f3429844df32e674b9e508bf5ebe).

Comment: Hey Thanks this works and also solves another problem I had :)